# Insert Many-to-Many entities into Entity Framework error

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I've struggled with this far too long now. I'm trying to insert records with relationships into database, code:

```
public class Innehåll
{
    public Innehåll(int antal)
    {
        this.Antal = antal;
        this.Frys= new HashSet<Frys>();
    }
    public Innehåll() { }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Antal { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Frys> Frys{ get; set; }        
}

public class Frys
{
    public Frys(string ort)
    {
        this.Ort = ort;
        this.Innehåll = new HashSet<Innehåll>();
    }
    public Frys() { }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Ort { get; set; }
    public int teslse { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Innehåll> Innehåll { get; set; }
}
```

And when I run this code;

```
Innehåll i1 = new Innehåll(10);
BoxInfo b = new BoxInfo
{
    Pris = 10,
    Typ = "Körv"
};

db.BoxInfos.Add(b);
db.Frysar.Add(frys);   
frys.Innehåll.Add(i1);
db.SaveChanges();
```

`frys` is declared through MVC Model Binding.

I get error on line `frys.Innehåll.Add(i1);`

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

Why I get this and how do I solve it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the looks of it, it can only be `frys` that's null. You initialize `Innehåll` in the constructor and you just created `i1`. But you should be able to establish this easily by debugging.